# Socket ReceiveFromAsync

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-5

This question is about how to proceed after receiving a 'false' return value from Socket.ReceiveFromAsync. In the examples around the net (I've seen more than a dozen), lots of code ignores the return value, and some code looks at the return value.

Most code that looks at the return value follows the Microsoft example by naming the result `willRaiseEvent` as shown below. A return value of TRUE means that ReceiveFromAsync will raise an event the next time it receives a packet. That is the normal case.

A return value of FALSE means that ReceiveFromAsync will NOT raise an event in the future because it has already completed a receive operation and has returned the data in the event argument parameter just passed to it. Therefore, "good" code (in the Microsoft style) should manually process the data just returned in the parameter, as shown below.

My question is, shouldn't "good" code loop while calling ReceiveFromAsync while false return values are being returned? That way the code could drain the queue of completed receive events until RFA finally said, "Okay, I have no more data for you; I will raise an event on the next completed receive event."

Is it appropriate or necessary to loop to avoid losing received data under busy conditions? Do those situations ever occur? I have never seen an example of looping in the callback, and no documentation talks about doing it. Even code that has been written for high performance usually concentrates on using a reusable pool technique to avoid repeated socket and event argument allocations but does not address this looping issue. Thank you.

```
  // ReceiveFromAsync returns true if it will notify you of the
  // next incoming receive. If it returns false, it means that
  // it will *NOT* notify you of a receive event because it has
  // a completed event ready to go. It will load data into the
  // event args structure just passed into it. Thus you should
  // manually process the data so you don't lose it.
  //
  // But how do you establish another receive event? Should the 
  // code here loop until it sees false from ReceiveFromAsync?
  var willRaiseEvent = ((Socket) sock).ReceiveFromAsync(rxArgs);
  if (! willRaiseEvent) {
    ProcessData(rxArgs);
  }
```

Comment: Returning `false` seems to be a common case you should handle actively, https://github.com/enclave-networks/research.udp-perf/blob/e5e5afd5107cd6d64dff951e0deaa5dca26d549a/Enclave.UdpPerf/UdpAwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.cs#L34 More hints in https://enclave.io/high-performance-udp-sockets-net5/

Comment: @LexLi Wow, thank you! That was some good reading. I didn't understand all their code, but when I traced down how they handled a false return value from ReceiveFromAsync, they handled the returned data _once_ if they could and then recorded a failure. In other words, they didn't seem to generate another receive action in the callback. My question is how do you generate another receive operation if you only take one action once inside the if (!willRaiseEvent) block? None of the doc says anything about it; thus the question. Thank you for the great references!